# SSRS Reportviewer v11 fails with large csv parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have a report built in SSRS 2008 and I have a problem when the user passed a large csv as a parameter to the ReportViewer component within a web page.

I have tested the full parameter within SSRS and the report is generated but when passing through the information via the ReportView a Javascript error is thrown

*Failing parameters*

https://somedomain.com/reportviewer.aspx?Path=/somedomain.com/Report&DateStart=1-Aug-2014&DateEnd=31-Aug-2014&LCRep=akal1,acor1,alan1,aavi1,acus1,arya1,amou1,abal1,afbo1,aack1,andr1,awan1,afuq1,amco1,abou1,afee1,abia1,anth1,asca1,apsi1,agol1,acol1,alab1,btar1,blee1,bmay1,bmcc1,bbou1,rbac1,bcol1,bcur1,rkom1,rtra1,bgmo1,bhat1,bshe1,brad1,bmor1,bffl1,BHur1,bmck1,btri1,bwoh1,bjem1,bomi1,bkmc1,cmeu1,cfer1,carl1,csan1,csie1,cber1,cwbl1,cjcc1,cmda1,cdro1,ceva1,cgha1,crol1,cwas1,chus1,chhe1,cpai1,cpod1,ccal1,cbee1,clyd1,ccas1,cbie1,cchu1,cphi1,damo1,dhug1,dcac1,drol1,dani1,dwon1,dhag1,dalb1,dbar1,dgol1,wgre1,dgre1,dloo1,dmac1,davi1,dawn1,dkun1,djan1,derr1,dpac1,dwig1,egor1,epit1,elei1,ejam1,eken1,emag1,emac1,ebur1,eric1,ewin2,egol1,emod1,efar1,floy1,fnep1,fmag1,fcha1,ghay1,gtuc1,gbab1,ewin1,gdem1,geoc1,gsla1,gjuk1,ggri1,hpuc1,heck1,hjca1,hiki1,imic1,ifer1,igon1,jacq1,jmwi1,jbye1,jgut1,jgam1,jaga1,jwes2,jber1,wbur1,jjer1,jmor1,jtay1,jwax1,jbra1,jkee1,jgue1,jlam1,jnau1,jpel1,jlid1,jnha1,jboh1,jmax1,jwen1,jsac1,jing1,jdow1,jgil1,jgri1,john1,joss1,jpro1,jgsh1,jsta1,jjva1,jsev1,jfis1,jcar1,jcof1,jcfe1,jwpa1,jleo1,knar1,kbut1,kcur1,kary1,kafo1,kqua1,kare1,kbri1,kbai1,kgal1,kmar1,ktin1,khor1,kjor1,kdle1,kmul1,kbit1,kbot1,kebe1,ksch1,lros1,lsie1,lgro1,lcai1,ldev1,llha1,lesl1,ljri1,llaf1,msam1,mwda1,mhya1,mwil1,mkle1,miac1,mboh1,mcap1,mcla1,mmck1,mpmu1,mswi1,mtre1,mshe1,mhee1,mmar1,mrob1,mrud1,mgal1,nhow1,nmac1,npar1,nbel1,nico1,nman1,nand1,peng1,pzon1,prob1,pall1,pber1,pdar1,pdoy1,pfis1,pgod1,plam1,pbel1,pmck1,pcas1,pjen1,pone1,pkas1,pgui1,plav1,rand1,rfur1,rpan1,rpoc1,rtor1,rjsc1,rsta1,rduv1,rkra1,rluo1,rpoh1,rmou1,rcjo1,rfar1,regr1,rtai1,rbej1,rcov1,rpas1,rqui1,rwar1,rkli1,rwow1,spec1,ssca1,sian1,sdhi1,scot1,rjun1,slod1,snic1,scot2,sean1,shar1,cosh1,shei1,smas1,silv1,smil1,ssny1,svaq1,agre1,sgur1,shbr1,sher1,sjmu1,spap1,sjro1,sser1,sske1,such1,sore1,tcol1,tsau1,tnap1,tnea1,tdie1,tjfa1,tmur1,tach1,tmin1,trit1,tdra1,tlac1,tnew1,tsik1,vwor1,vsor1,vjua1,vmoo1,vchi1,wawi1,wqch1,wbow1,whun1,wley1,wyat1,waba1,wwis1

This is the Javascript exception I get back.

> Unhandled exception at line 885, column 13 in
>   http://somedomain.com:54821/ScriptResource.axd?d=VSuDvN4lmXp8v30Y-Tdw_ULVtosEuP4ipSMcwgw1ALEydnNZvMTFeuT3gKKJbjEPOhKXYnOLoHZl9-dfg1JeFAnpDaWGe1i6ERWN4bL9ZaOEoZWt42dwIsT8R5we_2n8S2D9sjkYf43p-LOD6vL5jVd1mKYQjrDo5hNpHtcFx5D_-3QzpoOJZF9kKCx6injg0&t=ffffffffb53e74b8
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 404

*Passing query*

If I reduce the number of items in the LCRep parameter then the report is generated.

https://somedomain.com/reportviewer.aspx?Path=/somedomeain.com/report&DateStart=1-Aug-2014&DateEnd=31-Aug-2014&LCRep=akal1,acor1,alan1,aavi1,acus1,arya1,amou1,abal1,afbo1,aack1,andr1,awan1,afuq1,amco1,abou1,afee1,abia1,anth1,asca1,apsi1,agol1,acol1,alab1,btar1,blee1,bmay1,bmcc1,bbou1,rbac1,bcol1,bcur1,rkom1,rtra1,bgmo1,bhat1,bshe1,brad1,bmor1,bffl1,BHur1,bmck1,btri1,bwoh1,bjem1,bomi1,bkmc1,cmeu1,cfer1,carl1,csan1,csie1,cber1,cwbl1,cjcc1,cmda1,cdro1,ceva1,cgha1,crol1,cwas1,chus1,chhe1,cpai1,cpod1,ccal1,cbee1,clyd1,ccas1,cbie1,cchu1,cphi1,damo1,dhug1,dcac1,drol1,dani1,dwon1,dhag1,dalb1,dbar1,dgol1,wgre1,dgre1,dloo1,dmac1,davi1,dawn1,dkun1,djan1,derr1,dpac1,dwig1,egor1,epit1,elei1,ejam1,eken1,emag1,emac1,ebur1,eric1,ewin2,egol1,emod1,efar1,floy1,fnep1,fmag1,fcha1,ghay1,gtuc1,gbab1,ewin1,gdem1,geoc1,gsla1,gjuk1,ggri1,hpuc1,heck1,hjca1,hiki1,imic1,ifer1,igon1,jacq1,jmwi1,jbye1,jgut1,jgam1,jaga1,jwes2,jber1,wbur1,jjer1,jmor1,jtay1,jwax1,jbra1,jkee1,jgue1,jlam1,jnau1,jpel1,jlid1,jnha1,jboh1,jmax1,jwen1,jsac1,jing1,jdow1,jgil1,jgri1,john1,joss1,jpro1,jgsh1,jsta1,jjva1,jsev1,jfis1,jcar1,jcof1,jcfe1,jwpa1

Any idea why the extended parameter list is causing this failure?

**Edit**

The report is generated up to this point

http://somedomain.com/ReportViewer.aspx?Path=/Report&DateStart=1-Aug-2014&DateEnd=31-Aug-2014&LCRep=akal1,acor1,alan1,aavi1,acus1,arya1,amou1,abal1,afbo1,aack1,andr1,awan1,afuq1,amco1,abou1,afee1,abia1,anth1,asca1,apsi1,agol1,acol1,alab1,btar1,blee1,bmay1,bmcc1,bbou1,rbac1,bcol1,bcur1,rkom1,rtra1,bgmo1,bhat1,bshe1,brad1,bmor1,bffl1,BHur1,bmck1,btri1,bwoh1,bjem1,bomi1,bkmc1,cmeu1,cfer1,carl1,csan1,csie1,cber1,cwbl1,cjcc1,cmda1,cdro1,ceva1,cgha1,crol1,cwas1,chus1,chhe1,cpai1,cpod1,ccal1,cbee1,clyd1,ccas1,cbie1,cchu1,cphi1,damo1,dhug1,dcac1,drol1,dani1,dwon1,dhag1,dalb1,dbar1,dgol1,wgre1,dgre1,dloo1,dmac1,davi1,dawn1,dkun1,djan1,derr1,dpac1,dwig1,egor1,epit1,elei1,ejam1,eken1,emag1,emac1,ebur1,eric1,ewin2,egol1,emod1,efar1,floy1,fnep1,fmag1,fcha1,ghay1,gtuc1,gbab1,ewin1,gdem1,geoc1,gsla1,gjuk1,ggri1,hpuc1,heck1,hjca1,hiki1,imic1,ifer1,igon1,jacq1,jmwi1,jbye1,jgut1,jgam1,jaga1,jwes2,jber1,wbur1,jjer1,jmor1,jtay1,jwax1,jbra1,jkee1,jgue1,jlam1,jnau1,jpel1,jlid1,jnha1,jboh1,jmax1,jwen1,jsac1,jing1,jdow1,jgil1,jgri1,john1,joss1,jpro1,jgsh1,jsta1,jjva1,jsev1,jfis1,jcar1,jcof1,jcfe1,jwpa1,jleo1,knar1,kbut1,kcur1,kary1,kafo1,kqua1,kare1,kbri1,kbai1,kgal1,kmar1,ktin1,khor1,kjor1,kdle1,kmul1,kbit1,kbot1,kebe1,ksch1,lros1,lsie1,lgro1,lcai1,ldev1,llha1,lesl1,ljri1,llaf1,msam1,mwda1,mhya1,mwil1,mkle1,miac1,mboh1,mcap1,mcla1,mmck1,mpmu1,mswi1,mtre1,mshe1,mhee1,mmar1,mrob1,mrud1,mgal1,nhow1,nmac1,npar1,nbel1,nico1,nman1,nand1,peng1,pzon1,prob1,pall1,pber1,pdar1,pdoy1,pfis1,pgod1,plam1,pbel1,pmck1,pcas1,pjen1,pone1,pkas1,pgui1,plav1,rand1,rfur1

The LCRep parameter contains 242 items totaling 1451 characters including commas.

**Faulting Javascript**

Code breaks on the `throw error;` line

```
function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data) {
    if (this._request === executor.get_webRequest()) {
        this._processingRequest = false;
        this._additionalInput = null;
        this._request = null;
    }
    var handler = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("endRequest");
    var errorHandled = false;
    if (handler) {
        var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
        handler(this, eventArgs);
        errorHandled = eventArgs.get_errorHandled();
    }
    if (error && !errorHandled) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is on line 885 of the source code?

Comment: Updated question with the Javascript code from the ReportViewer component.

Comment: It seems to not like your error variable... what data type is that?

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem Which data type? This Javascript is from the Microsoft Report Viewer component.

Comment: Perhaps the javascript is running a urlencode on the URL, causing it to expand past the Internet Explorer URL length limitation of 2083.

Comment: @JC. I think you've hit the issue. If you want to create and answer perhaps referencing this http://support.microsoft.com/KB/208427 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers I will make as the answer.

Comment: I might have provided the spark, but you did the research. Glad you found it helpful. You might open another question asking about alternatives to really long multiselect parameters in querystrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is down to the length of the URL. This has been discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) Stackoverflow post and also in this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/208427) from Microsoft

[image]

I think JC. had the right idea that the encoding was pushing it over the length limitations and causing the strange failure in the ReportViewer. Thanks for the help JC.